# Can I stop the propagation of an event at a certain level?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

For example, I have a bunch of elements inside a #dialogbox div, can I somehow make sure that certain events don't propagate beyond it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use this

```
$(element).on('click', function(event){
  event.stopImmediatePropagation();
});
```

Comment: It doesn't answer the question "Can I stop the propagation of an event at a certain level?"

Comment: I have bound this to a click event. The idea is e.stopImmediatePropogation(). Add this code where is application. say if(i==1), like that!

Comment: 1. I'm not an OP 2. OP asked if he could stop the propagation not on the current element, but not propagate upper than some particular parent element

Comment: I think I'm confused. Perhaps the OP could clarify. I believe e.stopImmediatePropagation() does that. jQuery docs state 'Keeps the rest of the handlers from being executed and prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree.' Am I missing something?

Comment: Maybe the solution needs explaining. You basically want to call e.stopPropagation() or e.stopImmediatePropagation() on whichever binding you want to be the last to receive a bubbled event. It will stop it from that point. stopImmediatePropagation also cancels events on the same element. If we're not correctly addressing your question, a more detailed example might help.

Comment: yes it stops propagation starting at the very next level. for example take <div><span><a>asdsf</a></span</div> if I call a click even with stopImmediatePropagation on the anchor it will just stop there, I would like to konw if there's a way to stop it somewhere else, on the div for example.

Comment: Okay i just read your second comment. Are you saying if I do event.stopImmediatePropogation(); in the click event of the div, in my example, then I click on the anchor, the propagation of that click event will stop at the div?.

Comment: Simply, it is same as a break statement in most programming languages. Instead of terminating a control flow, you are terminating an event flow.

Comment: Yes. If you apply it to the div it should stop it on the div. Just make sure you call `stopProp**a**gation` and not `stopProp**o**gation`. I will check it in a fiddle real fast.

Comment: @Bogdan Does this http://jsfiddle.net/tracyfu/QU5qj/ demonstrate what you're looking for?

Comment: getting a bad gateway error on the jsfiddle, will try to implement the fix and let you know if it works.

Comment: okay i implemented the fix as follows `$j("#ferdialog").mousewheel(function(event) {     
     alert("test"); event.stopImmediatePropagation();               
  });`and i get the alert but the mousewheel event still seems to go trough.

Comment: so you mean. You want to stop the further mousewheelscrolling.

Comment: yep. Basically I want the rest of the page not to scroll up or down if the user attempts to scroll on a non-scrollable element inside the #ferdialog

Comment: No, and i'm not sure what the problem is. I mean event.stopImmediatePropagation() works for the click event, but not for the mousewheel.

Comment: try making it more specific, Mousewheel up and wheel down. try then!